# How to count the number of some specific leading character in a String, using only Regex?

Tags: elixir

Given an input string, I want to find the number of times a specific character is present in the String in the leading order, using only regular expressions. I have always used regex to just match expressions but never to count characters in it. Not really sure how to do it. So I am only looking for a solution to this problem using pattern matching.

For instance say my example string is **S = "0004fhjs0sjk0"**
And I need to count the number of leading **"0"s** in the string S, which is **3 in this case**. How to define a function which returns the count (3 here)

```
def get_leading_zeroes(value, character) do
...
end
```

I have already implemented a solution using recursion **but I want to do it using Regex.**

```
def get_leading_zeros(value, count) do
[h|t] = value
if h == "0" do
    get_leading_zeros(t, count+1)
else 
    count
end

get_leading_zeros(value |> String.graphemes, 0)
```

Comment: Will `character` only have one codepoint or can it be a long string? Also, did you try implementing this yourself? (if yes you should add the non-working code).

Comment: Sorry I updated the question. I solved it using recursion but was wondering if there was some other better way in Elixir to do it, mainly by just using pattern matching instead of checking for individual characters.

Answer (score 1):

With a recursion (better pattern matching + tail optimization):

```
defmodule M do
  def get_leading_zeros(input, acc \\ 0) # declaration for default
  def get_leading_zeros(<<"0", rest :: binary>>, acc),
    do: get_leading_zeros(rest, acc + 1) # recursive call when matches
  def get_leading_zeros(_, acc), do: acc # return accumulated
end
M.get_leading_zeros "0004fhjs0sjk0"
#⇒ 3
```

---

With regular expression:

```
with [match] <- Regex.run(~r/\A0*/, "0004fhjs0sjk0"),
  do: String.length(match)
```

---

Without additional calls:

```
with [{pos, _}] <-
     Regex.run(~r/[^0]/, # negative search
               "0004fhjs0sjk0",
               return: :index, capture: :first), # NOTE return: :index
  do: pos
```

or, vice versa:

```
with [{0, pos}] <-
     Regex.run(~r/0*/, # positive search
               "0004fhjs0sjk0",
               return: :index, capture: :first),
  do: pos
```

Please also check a valuable comment by @Dogbert below, but this is a matter of habit.

Comment: I'd go with `"0" <> rest` instead of `<<"0", rest :: binary>>`.

Answer (score 0):

```ex
def get_leading_char_count(str, char) do
  ~r/^#{char}*/
  |> Regex.run(str)
  |> Enum.at(0)
  |> String.length()
end

get_leading_char_count("0004fhjs0sjk0", 0)
# 3

get_leading_char_count("4fhjs0sjk0", 0)
# 0
```

*Note: I renamed the function in my example because you are passing in the zero as the second argument in your own example. If you pass something other than zero, the function name `get_leading_zeroes` will no longer make sense.*